# Multiclipboard Automate the boring Stuff

Tags: python, clipboard, shelve

I have some difficulties to run this program. You can see how to run it on Windows. But how does it work for Mac? For instance, `python3 mcb.py save spam`, when I type it into the console in Spyder it gives me this error message

```
python3 mcb.py spam
  File "<ipython-input-476-bd7c517010f3>", line 1
    python3 mcb.py spam
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I just run the program without putting any command in it creates a db file. Can you give me some instructions on how to run this program properly

```
#! python3
# mcb.pyw - create a multiclipboard tool
# Usage: py.exe mcb.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword.
#        py.exe mcb.pyw <keyword> - Loads keyword to clipboard.
#        py.exe mcb.pyw list - loads all keywords to clipboard.


import shelve, pyperclip, sys

#open the shelve
mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')

#save clipboard content
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
#either copy keys to clipboard or copy value of a key
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
       pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
       pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

#close out the shelve
mcbShelf.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run

```
python3 mcb.py spam
```

from *within Python* (via Spyder).

That command is meant to be run in a regular operating system terminal.

Try opening up [Terminal](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/terminal/welcome/mac), `cd`ing to the directory that holds `mcb.py`, and running the command there. Alternatively, install [a system-level terminal in Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal) and run it there.

Comment: Hey Chris thanks to have you back on board. I am in Visual Studio Code now, I am in the directory, (base) Tayfuns-MBP:~ tayfun$ ./mcb.py
(base) Tayfuns-MBP:~ tayfun$ ./mcb.py save spam
(base) Tayfuns-MBP:~ tayfun$.       When I run ./mcb.py it creates a mcb.db file then when I run ./mcb.py save spam or any other command from above it just accepts the command no error but it does not produce any result

Comment: @Hurricane, you've tried `./mcb.py list` after a few `./mcb.py save foo`s? What does that do?

Comment: Awesome thanks. ['terk', 'cold', 'zuop', 'foo', 'spam', 'fun', 'pythoniscool']. I pasted it out of curiosity into the editor and now I can also see things I saved to the different keywords. In the terminal nothing happens, it just runs the command and in a text editor I can see everything. Thank you Chris!!